# How to create jar of particular class used it another web application

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to create a web application where I like to use a database connection from jar file.
let's say I have one database connection class which has multiple methods I like to use this single class as a jar in my web application.

in my web application for any request mapping if I call database methods that should update in the database

**Sample DatabaseConnection class**

```
class DatabaseConnection{
        public int devDatabase(){


        }
        public int testDatabase(){


        }

        public int prodDatabase(){


        }
}
```

**Sample Controller**

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public  String test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {    

        return "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did setting the `jar` in maven/gradle dependency management tools did help you ?

Comment: does it matter? if in same jar or in different. i guess not.

Comment: Set the `package` type to `jar` in your build file. Then you can use the `jar` file as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Modules can solve your problem. Create a [multi-module](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-how-to-create-a-multi-module-project/) project.

here are some important points,

create a multi-module project in maven. (assume you are using maven)

```
<modules>
    <module>web</module>
    <module>orm</module>
    <module>core</module>
</modules>
```

assassin modules like this in your main pom.xml.

in ORM(Object-relational mapping)'s pom.xml tell the packaging as **jar**

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>someID</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

then you can use this module as a dependency in other modules. eg :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>hms-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```